# How to combine a lot of csv files horizontally (not stack data by column) in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a lot of csv files with same rownames and colnames, I want combine them by row names, however, all of the examples I found just did it like stacking the data vertically.

for example what I can do now:

```
filenames <- list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/GCMS_experiment/Raw TIC_GCMS_experi", pattern=".csv", full.names=TRUE)
data <- rbindlist(lapply(filenames,fread))
```

then output this "Read 93.0% of 4323116 rows
Read 4323116 rows and 5 (of 5) columns",  this stacking my data, because for one csv file, I have 5 columns and 20684 rows (209 csv files in total).

what I want is combine them by rows,i.e gave me a final csv file containing 20684 rows, 209*5 columns. i.e combine data horizontally not stacking data vertically.

what should I do for the code? thank you

Comment: you want to cbind the data and need 20684 columns ? your question is not clear

Comment: `do.call(cbind, lapply(filenames, fread))` maybe? Be aware that this might blow up your memory.

Comment: Hi thanks. But it did the same as my code. Do you have other solution?

Comment: You should try `rbind` instead or `cbind` in LAP's code.

Comment: Because you are using `fread` to import the csv files, they are being imported as a `data.table`. The `data.table` implementation has some very strict rules to maintain its rigid framework. One problem this appears to cause involves `cbind`. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#ive-noticed-that-basecbind.data.frame-and-baserbind.data.frame-appear-to-be-changed-by-data.table.-how-is-this-possible-why. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example in order to let us better try and help you.